# Is there a term for "from X to Y" that includes everything?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for "from X to Y" that includes everything?
Like every animal, "from snail to elephant." 
Or "through thick and thin."

Added later:
Sorry, I think I was misunderstood - I meant to ask for a technical term to describe that concept, rather than a parallel term for the concept. So, for example, a merism is a way or referring to a whole by its parts, but is there a term that means "a way to refer to the whole by saying 'from X to Y'?"

Comment: the whole kit and caboodle?

Comment: @curious-proofreader I honestly thought it was "kitten caboodle"!

Comment: that's a common mistake, DogLover.  Like say "tenterhooks".

Comment: "From soup to nuts, inclusive" sounds pretty scientific.

Answer (score 2):

The remarkably simple answer here is

> from A to Z.

*Is there a term for 'from X to Y' that includes everything?*  Yes, the term is *from A to Z*.

---

You now ask, I believe, essentially, a rather specific question about a variant of the obscure word merism: I suggest, close out this question and ask a new one about that.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was misunderstood - I meant to ask for a technical term to describe that concept, rather than a parallel term for the concept. So, for example, a merism is a way or referring to a whole by its parts, but is there a term that means "a way to refer to the whole by saying 'from X to Y'?"